# Tools and environments for nokia asha development in 2022

Tags: java, nokia-s40

It sounds silly but does anyone have the documentation and tools to build an app for Nokia Asha? I want to create a simple app for my old Asha 501. Thanks very much.

Note: Most of the links have been removed so I would like to have the general instructions in this question

Comment: not silly, but nostalgic.

Comment: I found the IDE for it, now I'm missing the documentation to start. Nostalgic things make me feel interesting, haha.